# Generated file in Crontab is empty

Tags: grep, cron, laravel-artisan, goaccess

I need help with this one. An Artisan command is being run by crontab to analyze a logfile and generate a report into an HTML format.

Here is the line of code in the command that is being executed by crontab:

```
$today = date("d/M/Y");
exec('grep "$today" /path_to_logfile | goaccess -a > /path_of_generated_HTML_file');
exit();
```

Unfortunately, the file being generated by cron is empty but when you execute the same code directly in the terminal, it successfully generates an html file. I appreciate your help guys.

Comment: Most probably you have issues with PATH variable. I would assume that code in cron ("goaccess" specifically) is not in PATH.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because your `PATH` is configured incorrectly when running under `crontab`. For most implementations of `crontab`, you can simply specify the `PATH` on the first line on the crontab file opened with `crontab -e`:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

You could also set the path inside PHP if you so desire:

```php
<?php

putenv('PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin');

$today = date("d/M/Y");
exec('grep "$today" /path_to_logfile | goaccess -a > /path_of_generated_HTML_file');
exit;
```